# Release Management Server for TFS 2018

Tags: tfs

I would like to have a separate release management server for TFS 2018. I can't find any documentation that tells me how to do this. In older versions of TFS, it was a separate install, but I am not seeing anything in the 2018 version.

Comment: Just as Daniel saied, Release Management features have been integrated into the Build & Release hub since TFS 2015, and no new features will be added to the old server and client versions of Release Management, See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/release/previous-version/config-and-system-variables

Answer (score 1):

Release Management Server is deprecated. It has not received updates since TFS 2015, and will not receive updates going forward.

Since TFS 2015, the Release hub is a first-class part of TFS. You can find it under the "Build and Release" section.